# Bootstrap Dialog error (Cannot call a class as a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a dialog for my delete button i am using bootstrap3-dialog, this is the examples page: http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Modal-Dialog-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-Bootstrap-3-Dialog/examples/

when i click on my button i am getting an error bootstrap.js:36 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function, this is what i have now:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.btn-delete', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        confirm_dialog($(this).parent('form'));
    });

    function confirm_dialog(form){
        //console.log(form);
        BootstrapDialog.show({

            title: '{{ trans('alerts.backend.settings.deleting_record') }}',
            message: '{{ trans('alerts.backend.settings.delete_confirmation_msg') }}',
            buttons: [ {
                icon: 'fa fa-check',
                label: '{{ trans('alerts.backend.settings.yes') }}',
                cssClass: 'btn-success btn-xs',
                action: function(){
                    form.submit();
                }
            }, {
                icon: 'fa fa-remove',
                label: '{{ trans('alerts.backend.settings.no') }}',
                cssClass: 'btn-danger btn-xs',
                action: function(dialogItself){
                    dialogItself.close();
                }
            }]
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

this is my button helper:

```
function delete_btn($route, $id)
{
    $btn = Form::open(array("method"=>"DELETE", "route" => array($route, $id), 'class' => 'form-inline', 'style'=>'display:inline')).'
       <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete" id="btn-delete"  data-rel="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="'.trans('strings.backend.general.delete').'"><i style="color:white;" class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>'.Form::close();
    return $btn;
}
```

and this is how i am calling it in my view:

{!! delete_btn('admin.clients.destroy', $client->id) !!}

Im getting the error when i click on my delete button and dont get the dialog, any help will be really appreciated, thank you.

Comment: If you are using BootstrapDialog3 with Bootstrap 4 (beta), there are issues. https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog/issues/357